# How to get max objectid from pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

How would you get the max ObjectId from a table using pymongo? I'm attempting to use `find_one()`, but I don't know how to do a sort.

```
my_mongo_handler.findone({}, {'_id': -1})
```

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to do something like the following

```
my_mongo_handler.findone({}).sort({'_id': -1})
```

for future reference, the mongo documentation is really quite good https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/

Comment: I'm trying to do this in python, not mongo.

Answer (score 1):

You can also pass `sort` parameter to `find_one`:

```
result = my_mongo_handler.find_one(sort=[('_id', -1)])
```